# Calculate end of quarter dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

I am trying to find all the end of quarter dates between two dates. I would also like to use the maximum date for the current / in-progress quarter.

```
def calculate_quarters(start_yyyy_mm_dd, end_yyyy_mm_dd):
     ...
     ...
     ...

x = calculate_quarters('2020-01-01', '2021-01-07')
print(x)

> ['2020-03-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-09-30', '2020-12-31', '2021-01-07']
```

I have looked at some previous answers and see we can calculate the end of quarter like this:

```
>>> d = datetime.date.today()
>>> datetime.date(year=d.year, month=((d.month % 3) + 1) * 3 + 1, day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
datetime.date(2015, 9, 30)
```

However I'm unsure how to adapt it to a range and handle incomplete quarters.

Comment: What is logic for add `'2021-01-07'` ?

Comment: I don't understand your question but modified by original question to hopefully make it more clear

Comment: I dont understand `I would also like to use the maximum date for the current / in-progress quarter.`, it means there is added end datetime ?

Comment: As the end date is `2021-01-07` it represents 2021 Q1 but 2021 Q1 is *currently* incomplete as we are in February now. For such a case I don't want the end of quarter date but instead the `end_yyyy_mm_dd` as it max date in the current quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need matching only quarters between both dates use [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) for quartes, convert to timestamps by [`PeriodIndex.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.to_timestamp.html), floor by [`DatetimeIndex.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html) and last add last incomplete end timestamp if not exist in range by [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html):

```
def calculate_quarters(s, e):
    r = pd.period_range(s, e, freq='Q').to_timestamp(how='end').normalize()
    return r[(r > s) & (r < e)].union(pd.to_datetime([e])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist()


print (calculate_quarters('2020-01-01', '2021-01-07'))
['2020-03-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-09-30', '2020-12-31','2021-01-07']
```

---

```
def calculate_quarters(s, e):
    r = pd.period_range(s, e, freq='Q').to_timestamp(how='end').normalize()
    return r[(r > s) & (r < e)].union(pd.to_datetime([e])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist()


print (calculate_quarters('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'))
['2020-03-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-09-30', '2020-12-31']
```

Comment: I would suggest modifying the `return` to this: `return (r[(r > s) & (r < e)].union(pd.to_datetime([e]))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist()`. This will result a list of strings rather than a DatetimeIndex